# mysql PDO Stored Procedure call fails execution on a php page

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the below PHP code for a mysql PDO stored procedure call, with one input parameter and one output parameter.

When I specify a hard-coded string like 'RQ000448' for the input parameter, the stored procedure call works successfully.

But I want to be able to pass the value of the $_POST variable I retrieve in the php page in the place of the hard-coded string:

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
include("DBConnect.php");
try {
$conn = OpenCon();

$data = $_POST['reqnum'];

$stmt = $conn->prepare("CALL createOrder(:inval, @o_message)");
//$stmt->bindValue(':inval', $data , PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT);       // << This line does not work
$stmt->bindValue(':inval', 'RQ000448' , PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT);    // << This line works
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->closeCursor();

$output = $conn->query("select @o_message")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);   
var_dump($output); // array('o_message'=>value)

//close connection
CloseCon($conn);
}
catch(Exception $e) {
      echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

So how can I the get the above code to work using the variable $data in the place of the string 'RQ000448'.
Or is there any alternative way that I can resolve the problem?

Any suggestions will be tremendously helpful!  Thank you in advance!!

Comment: What do you mean by _"does not work"_? What happens that is unexpected? Have you tried verifying the value of `$data`?

Comment: Why are you using `PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT` for `:inval`? It doesn't appear to be an output parameter.

Comment: @Phil: thanks for taking a look! When I specify $data for the input parameter, the stored procedure returns null, when I am expecting a string value as output.

Comment: @Phil: If I use PDO::PARAM_INPUT, it is throwing the error:  Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined class constant 'PARAM_INPUT' in C:\Apache24\htdocs\BackEndApp\createOrder.php

Comment: @Phil: when I do a var_dump($data), I get  ---->   string(8) "RQ000448"

Comment: Try just `$stmt->bindParam(':inval', $data);`. Also, what does the signature for your stored procedure look like?

Comment: Thank you Phil. I tried  ` $stmt->bindParam(':inval', $data); ` When I do a var_dump of $output I get this:  `array(1) { ["@o_message"]=> NULL }`

Comment: Thank you Phil. I tried  `$stmt->bindParam(':inval', $data);` When I do a var_dump of $output I get this:  `array(1) { ["@o_message"]=> NULL }`  And the stored procedure signature is: `CREATE PROCEDURE `createOrder`(in reqno varchar(20), out custph varchar(20))
BEGIN
 select custphone
 into custph 
 from request
 where requestnum = reqno;
END;`